# Circuit working in simulation but not in real life

Tags: rf, oscillator, radio

I have the following Colpitts oscillator circuit, which seems to work rather well in LTspice. When I breadboard it, however, and check the output with an oscilloscope there is nothing.

What could be the cause of this?

I have tried the same circuit on both a breadboard and a perfboard, neither works.

[image: The circuit in question.]

Comment: Breadboards have a ton of parasitic capacitance, inductance, and resistance. Your carefully chosen picofarad-range capacitances are likely being swamped out by those parasitics. The perfboard is _probably_ not that great either because it lacks a reference plane under the traces, so it could also be screwing up your circuit. It's possible that there are other issues with the design that are causing problems, but I'm not familiar enough with Colpitts circuits to dig into that side of things.

Comment: Will add Nyquist diagrams to show ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm actually kind of surprised it works even in simulation.

If you want to go by rules of thumb, for a low-power oscillator like this you should start with an inductor reactance of \$200\Omega\$ to \$500 \Omega\$ at your design frequency, then choose tank capacitors with twice that reactance.  Your tank's characteristic impedance (\$\sqrt{L_1 / \left(C_1 \| C_2 \right)}\$) is more like \$12\Omega\$ -- this might work for a power oscillator, but that's not what you're designing.

Then, you want to make sure that your coupling capacitor (C4) has a low-enough reactance to really couple the tank circuit's energy into the amplifier.  You've chosen \$X_{C4} \simeq 1200 \Omega \$, which is going to be quite large in comparison to the input impedance of your amplifier at 2MHz.

I suggest you do this:

- Break the wire going from the tank circuit to C4
- Connect C4 to an AC voltage source, label that net as "Vin"
- Label the net at the junction of L1 and C2 as "Vout"
- Do an AC analysis, with a frequency sweep from 1MHz to 3MHz.
- Plot Vout / Vin
- Adjust your various component values so that you have *at least 6dB of gain at the point where the phase is zero*.
- For extra points, make that zero-phase crossing happen at your desired oscillation frequency.
- For more extra points, make sure that the slope of the phase is highest where it crosses zero.

Then try *those* component values and see how your circuit works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try this and see if I can improve it. The reason C4 is such a high reactance is because when I put it to a value it stopped oscillating (could software error possibly be the reason for this?).

Comment: Do you mean when you put it to a _higher_ value it stopped oscillating?  It's hard to say why this might be, although using a resistor at R1 instead of a choke isn't going to do you any favors, and you may be reflecting enough load back to the amplifier output that it bogs down and can't provide enough gain.

Comment: It looks like you're using LTSpice -- so no, there's very little chance that you're seeing the result of a software bug.

Answer (score 0):

Nyquist diagram of oscillator ...

Show the needed value for cc3 capacitor.

[image]